# How to post to SharePoint NewsFeed using Remote Event Receiver?

Tags: event-receivers, remote-event-receiver

I tried to post to SharePoint NewsFeed via Remote Event Receiver.

`public void ProcessOneWayEvent(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
        {
            ClientContext context = TokenHelper.CreateRemoteEventReceiverClientContext(properties);
            PeopleManager peopleManager = new PeopleManager(context); 
}`

But it seems I cant construct a people manager object inside the event receiver code. The log messages I put after the construction of `PeopleManager` doesn't execute.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it is not possible because access token is not related to any user. 
Alternative way it create own client context, using login and password any real user.