# How to create an entry in user's newsfeed when listItem is created?

Tags: sharepoint-online, newsfeed

I need to create newsfeed post when user adds an Item to a particular list in sharepoint online. I tried remote event receivers, workflows and sandboxed solutions without any luck. Can someone point me to an article explaining how to post to newsfeed when an item is added to a list?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to post to sharepoint newsfeed using remote event reciever?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/80245/how-to-post-to-sharepoint-newsfeed-using-remote-event-reciever)

Answer (score 0):

You can create of list workflow that will be started when an item is created. 
Unfortunately Sharepoint doesn't have workflow action for posting to microfeed, but you can use 3rd party action [Post to microfeed](http://plumsail.com/workflow-actions-pack/docs/social-integration/#PostToMF).

This is a one workflow actions from [Workflow Actions Pack](http://plumsail.com/workflow-actions-pack/). I participate in development of this product. It works for SharePoint 2013 as well as for SharePoint Online in Office 365.

Comment: Thanks for the information, Can you share what APIs used by this custom action in Office 365?